# installing RadRails, "no tty present and no askpass program specified"

Tags: ubuntu, passwords, installation, radrails

I am new to Linux. I'm on a dualboot machine, working in Ubuntu. I'm trying to install RadRails, but every time I try to let RadRails audo-install gems, I am asked for my password to get into root. I know that I'm putting in the correct password, but I am ending up entering the password for every gem and I keep getting the error, "no tty present and no askpass program specified". Yet after it says, "sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts" it says that the gem was installed.

After it goes through every gem, I run into an error with RadRails that says "'Showing Startup Page' has encountered a problem. An internal error has occured." Then when I click okay it says, "An SWT error has occurred. You are recommended to exit the workbench. Subsequent errors may happen and may terminate the workbench without warning. Do you want to exit the workbench?" Every time I restart RadRails, the exact same thing happens.

I've read online that I could install askpass and then set the askpass variable in the sudoers file, or I could disable the password (which I would rather not do).

Does anyone know what I should do? If it's to use askpass, can you please walk me through on how to do it? I don't know many shell commands and have been struggling this and just getting the Oracle JDK install for a couple of days now. Please please please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should never rely on the IDE to do everything for you. IDE's make writing code in a programming language easier and quicker, they should not replace knowledge of how the programming language is compiled/interpreted and executed. You need to become comfortable and skilled at using the command line tools available no matter the programming language you are trying to use. This is especially true when it comes to Ruby and Rails in a Linux environment. Programming in the Linux environment requires a good working knowledge of the terminal (Linux command line).

I used RVM to manage my Ruby installations as well as Gemsets to separate my development environments when I have multiple Rails web applications which have different setups (different Ruby versions, different rails versions, or different gem versions).

Here is a blog post I wrote a few years ago which outlines how to setup RVM, Ruby, and Rails on a Linux Mint system. Mint is a derivative of Ubuntu, which you are using, and the install and setup instructions should be pretty darn close.

http://timsbytes.blogspot.com/2011/03/rvm-ruby-rails-on-linux-mint.html

Here is the URL to RVM's website if you want to understand how it works and how it manages Rubies and Gems.

https://rvm.io/

Here is a link to how to install the Oracle JDK on a Linux machine. Again a little older post so you will need to change the Java JDK version numbers in the commands to the latest version you wish to use.

http://timsbytes.blogspot.com/2012/11/mint-13-installing-oracle-jdk-7.html

Comment: Thank you!!! I think I've got it all installed. As you mentioned, there were a few differences, but because of the help in the terminal, I was able to figure it out pretty easily.